# Android, howto catch a mystic system exception

Tags: android, exception

There is an exceptions, which I got in Android on drag. 
Google doesnt know about this exception.

**Question:**
Any Idea, what to override to catch this exception? Something seems to hppen inside of the system, because all the listed classes are frameworks native classes.

```
Window Session Crash
java.lang.IllegalStateException: reportDropResult() by non-recipient
    at com.android.server.wm.Session.reportDropResult(Session.java:307)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:369)
    at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:111)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: reportDropResult() by non-recipient
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1329)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.reportDropResult(IWindowSession.java:900)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleDragEvent(ViewRoot.java:3015)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2164)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'm not sure catching it (and swallowing it?) is the best solution... This is probably caused by a bug on your code to begin with, you'd better find and fix that. Sorry not to be able to help more than that, I'm not familiar with that version of the code :(

Comment: this exception happens, when my DragEvent is allready handled. The debugger shows, that the handled `DragEvents` are passed up the View tree anyway and some of the root Views seem to trigger the exception. My code does not have mush in common with that happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is an exceptions, which I got in Android on drag. Google doesnt know about this exception.

Since I can't find a `reportDropResult()` in the Android 2.3 source, I am guessing that this is from the new drag-and-drop framework introduced with Honeycomb.

> Any Idea, what to override to catch this exception?

You can't override anything to catch that exception. To catch unhandled exceptions, use `Thread` and `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`.